# Why is it possible to run a java project but only the Main.class file?

Tags: java

I use Netbeans to code java. And I have downloaded a java project on the net and found that in the source package there is only one file Main.class but when I press F6 to run, the project is still running. I wonder why the project can still run without any .java files.

[image]

Comment: stop downloading professional IDE's if you don't know the basics. You can't execute .java files, only .class files, that's why you have to compile the .java files you create before being able to run it.

Comment: @Stultuske the first sentence of your comment is really unnecessary and, frankly, false. Netbeans is fine for all levels.

Comment: Having said that, @HoangDinhNhat why would you expect *not* to be able to run it?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca considering I've worked with a "Senior Swing Developer" (never heard that title before or after), I tend to disagree. The man couldn't create the simplest JFrame screen to save his life, since we were employed in a company that blacklisted NetBeans as IDE. Yes, it can be used by anyone, however for many it means they won't learn about the actual stuff, they'll just learn to use the IDE.

Comment: @Stultuske I'm trying to make sense of this: A "Senior Swing Developer" can't make a simple JFrame in a company that didn't use Netbeans therefore IDEs are bad ? Are you saying the IDE hid too much of the basics and the dev was unable to function without it ?

Comment: @John3136 I'm saying that as long as he had his wyiswyg editor, the result worked. The moment he was supposed to know what to do himself, he completely blacked out.
It's easy to right-click a class and choose "run", but I do think it's somewhat important to understand what it is you are running.

Comment: @Stultuske Yep. That's what I thought you were saying. Makes sense now :-)

Comment: @Stultuske on the other hand you could say that hiding the "complexity" of compiling, running etc while learning the actual language could be valuable too.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Java. And usually, in the source package, a .java file containing the main function is needed for the compiler to choose. But if it is Main.class, how will the compiler choose?

Comment: @HoangDinhNhat because `Main.class` contains itself the `main` method. So it can be run.

Comment: @HoangDinhNhat .java files aren't necessary at all. A .java file is a source file, it can't be run. the .class file is the compiled, and (if a main method is provided in it) runnable version of it

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that is indeed one way to look at it, but I've seen way to many people writing entire apps (because the IDE makes it so easy) only to realize it doesn't compile, since they don't understand scopes, data types, can't read stack traces, ... Quite a bit of programmers who are trying to build the proverbial house and thinking they can build the basement along with the walls. I'd rather see the foundation of the building done, before trying to finish it all

Comment: @Stultuske Technically in newer JDKs you can run a `.java` file, provided it's self-contained: https://openjdk.org/jeps/330

Answer (score 0):

typically,

1. you need a xx.java file(with main method in it)
2. compile it javac xx.java(.class file get generated)
3. run it with java xx(only using the .class file)

it will run if there is only the .class

Comment: meaning, you don't actually need a .java file if you download a compiled version of a project

Comment: yeah, the java files are called source files, jvm don`t use that, jvm uses .class files to actually execute the logics, there are a lot assemble code in the .class file. You can check javap https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

normally if I want to see how the code actually executed, I will javap -v xx.class, and get the detail info

Comment: that was the actual question. The OP thought the .java files were required to execute it